# Nginx get response body in custom default-backend

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, nginx-ingress

I developed my own custom default-backend in Java and it works but I want to also handle 400 codes and some services have to response with provided specific error codes in response body. Is it possible to receive response body received in service which fails in default-backend? For now in default-backend I can only see headers and body which was sent to service but I can't get response sent from specific service. For example service1 returns 400 code with response body
{
"errorCode": "INVALID_USER",
"message": "User not found or invalid"
}
and I want to get this response body in my default-backend and pass it as response to the client.

I tried to get response body directly from HttpServletRequest but its body which client was sending to server, not body received as response from service.